# Recommendation for locale on server: ISO (latin) or UTF-8

Tags: iso, localization, utf-8

What is the recommended locale setting on a server that is used as an web and database server.
Are there any drawbacks not using UTF-8 as default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some legacy application might not like it, but you should definitely use UTF-8 for new installations.

- for converting files (the contents) you can use iconv(1)
- for converting filenames you can use convmv(1)

Other special applications (application generated data) might require other considerations.

Answer (score 0):

all newer application think u use UTF-8.

utf-8 use slightly more space for store(2 bytes character) but more compatible for multi-language.
so if ur database have alot of text inside, using locale preferable. but UTF-8 still more compatible.